# Match multiple results single line php regex

Tags: php, regex

I would like to match multiple results on a single line string but I am only able to get the last iteration on the result I excpected.

For example I have this string : `<ul><li><a href="#">test1</a></li><li><a href="#">test2</a></li><a href="#">test3</a></li></ul>`

I would like to get :

test1
test2
test3

As result but I only get "test3"

I used this regex `<ul>(<li><a.*>(.*)<\/a><\/li>)*<\/ul>` on : https://regex101.com/ but I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: `preg_match_all` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Well, the pattern is wrong. Not each `<li>` is enclosed by an `<ul>`. You'll have to use two regexps for context/simplicity. While unversed use a DOM traversal frontend: `qphtml($html, "ul li")`

Comment: @mario: I guess that's just an error in the question description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a parser instead:

```
<?php

$html = <<<DATA
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
</ul>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

$links = $xpath->query("//li/a");
foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo $link->textContent;
}

?>
```

This sets up the `DOM` and uses an `xpath` expression to get the element(s).

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
(?<=(<a href="#">))([\s\S]| |w\[0-9]| )+?(?=(<\/a>))
or
(?<=(">))([\s\S]| |w\[0-9]| )+?(?=(<\/a>))
or
(?<=(<a href="#">))(.)+?(?=(<\/a>))
```

link with example:
https://regex101.com/r/MHnxxh/1
or
https://regex101.com/r/MHnxxh/2

```
<?php
$str = '
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
</ul>
';

preg_match_all('/(?<=(#">))([\s\S]| |w\[0-9]| )+?(?=(<\/a>))/', $str,   $matches);

// display array if need
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);

// display list
foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {
  echo $value ."\r\n";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("\#\"\>[a-z]\w+\<\/\a\>,
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)
```

this the regex pattern....try this 
("#\">[a-z]\w+\</\a>)

this will extract only all text strings....

Answer (score 0):

you cane use of **preg_replace**

```
     $test = '<ul><li><a href="#">test1</a></li><li><a href="#">test2</a></li><a href="#">test3</a></li></ul>';
        echo preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '  ', $test);
```